# Disable logging of ViewExpiredException

Tags: jsf

The ViewExpriedException is always logged in the server log file.

```
2013-02-23 10:24:10,165 ERROR [org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[jboss.web].[localhost].[/proshop].[FacesServlet]] 14-dac@172.19.15.65 (ajp-0.0.0.0-8009-6) Servlet.service() for servlet FacesServlet threw exception: javax.faces.application.ViewExpiredException: viewId:/index.jsf - La vue «/index.jsf» n?a pas pu être restaurée.
```

How can I avoid the logging of this Exception

Answer (score 0):

You should not avoid loggin `ViewExpiredException`, you should handle it.

A good link on this subject is this: [Dealing Gracefully with ViewExpiredException in JSF2](https://web.archive.org/web/20140926062323/http://weblogs.java.net/blog/edburns/archive/2009/09/03/dealing-gracefully-viewexpiredexception-jsf2).

Comment: The handling of the exception works fine but it is still logged in the server log! What can I do?